# Antivirus software flags website with "Caution: This site may contain content that could affect your online security" in Google Search results

Tags: google-search, security, categories

I'm a web developer. A local installation of the WebRoot antivirus software is flagging my client's construction website with the warning "Caution: This site may contain content that could affect your online security" in Google Search results.

Even though there probably aren't very many people running that specific software, I'd like to prevent that happening if I can.

I was able to enter the site URL at [this BrightCloud URL](https://www.brightcloud.com/tools/url-ip-lookup.php#) and see why, but the only reason in this case for the warning is "low popularity", which isn't explained. There is a form to "Request a reputation change", but it's unclear whether that would help.

**Has anyone else seen this issue before and solved it in a way that can easily be applied to multiple websites?**

Ideally I would use any solution on every website I look after, not just this one, and submitting a hundred websites through their online form doesn't seem like an elegant solution.

Comment: I have seen something similar, almost a decade ago. Some browser plugin that basically flagged any site that got very little traffic as "potentially dangerous". The thing is, I believe it was entirely based on how many of the plugin's own users interacted with the website, so there was little chance that a local business website would get enough traffic to overcome the problem. You might be able to request your site getting audited the software creators. We used to have to do that with Norton.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise checking with Google and Bing for any real security flags/recommendations.

- **Google**: Go to *Google Search Console*, and look for Security Issues
- **Bing**: Go to *Webmasters Tools*, and see if any warnings are present

As per **WebRoot** itself, you could try to create a whitelist of the IPs, so that they aren't flagged by the company's software.

Instructions on how to do that are here:
https://docs.webroot.com/us/en/business/wsab_endpointprotection_adminguide/Content/UsingOverrides/CreatingWhitelistOverrides.htm